# Apache Jmeter Ramp-up period

Tags: apache, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is there any difference between **Number of threads: 5 & Rampup period: 1 sec** vs **Number of threads: 50 & Rampup period: 10 secs** in jmeter configuration? I thought they are logically same but the performance result looks different. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, two cases you have wrote are the same. Performance difference you are getting is caused by number of users. It would be good if you could share  your test plan, so we can see what is making that difference...

Useful links on ramp-up:

- [Thread Group - Apache](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/08/05/ramp-up-period-in-jmeter/)
- [skill-guru.com - The ramp-up period](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)